# Using if statement to deal cards

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I am trying to deal an x amount of cards to a player depending on how many they already have in their hand (max of 5). But to insure that you don't get dealt the same card twice, or dealt a card that has already been played I've used an if Statement.

```
Card[] hand = new Card[5];
public void dealCard() {
  int cardCount = 0;
  Random ran = new Random();

  if (cardCount < 5) {
    int times = 5 - cardCount;
    for (int l = 0; l < times; l++) {
      int index = ran.nextInt(deck.length);
      if (deck[index] != null) {
        hand[cardCount] = deck[index];
        deck[index] = null;
        cardCount++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seemed to work at first but every so often the last card, and its always the last card, is null. I was told that it would probably be better to use a while loop instead, but just for the purpose of learning what have I done wrong here.

Comment: You could use a `Set`  to prevent duplicates

Comment: `nextInt(x)` returns an int between in `[0, x[` that might be your issue

Comment: Since `cardCount` is initialized with `0`, you do not need the outermost `if`. Also, you need to take action if `deck[index] == null`, because your `for` loop will always be executed exactly 5 times,  no matter how often you eoncouter a `null` value

Comment: Where is your `deck` declaration ?

Comment: It might make more sense to start with a deck, and remove cards from it to deal. Then you don't have to think about most of this.

Comment: Hello Angelica. I would think a better approach to the problem would be to create a “CardDecK” class. With the class you would create a new deck, deal X cards from the deck, shuffle the deck… etc. This way you can keep the card deck methods hidden from the user and avoid having to manage the card deck directly in your code.  Also, I would think a list would work better than array. With a list of 52 cards, and say the user wants to get 5 cards, randomly pick a card from the list, then remove it from the deck and possibly have another list of Dealt Cards. Just a thought.

Comment: The easiest way to deal cards is exactly like what you do in the real world: shuffle the deck and deal the top n cards. In code, you would create a deck as a list of all the cards, call `Collections.shuffle(deck)`, then use the first n elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop is always executed exactly five times, no matter how often you encounter a `null` within the loop's body. You can verify this by manipulating the size of `deck` to something `< 5`. If your method were working correct, it should get caught in an endless loop. instead, you will get at least `5 - deck.size` many `null`s. A quick& dirty fix would be to decremt `l` in case you encounter a `null`:

```
if (deck[index] != null) {
    // ...
} else /* if (deck[index] == null) */ {
    --l;
}
```

I would recommend a different strategy alltogether. Instead of generating a random index every time you want to draw a card, you could determin the order of all cards up-front, e.g. with the [Fisher-Yates-Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). This way, you need only to remember how many cards were drawn and extract the next card from your array/list/queue.